# How do I keep my screen contents centered and also have a scrollbar in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I started learning QT but I'm having difficulty keeping a QVBoxLayout centered but also having the ScrollArea remain functional.

I've searched for a solution online and everyone keeps telling me that a ScrollArea should have a widget within it and not a layout but when I do that the ScrollArea starts functioning but the QVBoxLayout no longer stays in the center of the window.

Here's my mainwindow.cpp file's contents:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QObject>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
    QVBoxLayout *innerVerticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    verticalLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    QWidget *verticalLayoutWidgetContainer = new QWidget();
    verticalLayoutWidgetContainer->setLayout(verticalLayout);
    verticalLayoutWidgetContainer->setFixedWidth(1000);


    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    horizontalLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    QPushButton *leftButton = new QPushButton("Left Button");
    leftButton->setFixedWidth(100);
    QPushButton *rightButton = new QPushButton("Right Button");
    rightButton->setFixedWidth(100);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(leftButton, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(rightButton, 0, Qt::AlignRight);


    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout1 = new QHBoxLayout;
    horizontalLayout1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    QPushButton *centerButton = new QPushButton("Center Button");
    centerButton->setFixedWidth(100);
    horizontalLayout1->addWidget(centerButton, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter);

    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout2 = new QHBoxLayout;
    horizontalLayout2->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    QPushButton *rightButton1 = new QPushButton("Right Button");
    rightButton1->setFixedWidth(100);
    horizontalLayout2->addWidget(rightButton1, 0, Qt::AlignRight);


    verticalLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout, 0);
    verticalLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout1, 0);
    verticalLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout2, 0);

    innerVerticalLayout->addWidget(verticalLayoutWidgetContainer, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);
    scrollArea->setLayout(innerVerticalLayout);
    this->setCentralWidget(scrollArea);  
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 delete ui;
}
```

Edit: Adding links to show how the app works when I have a layout/widget in the ScrollArea and how I would like it to work.

Link 1: How the ScrollArea works with a layout in it. https://i.imgur.com/oJghW1O.mp4
The ScrollArea doesn't work but the layout behaves as I intended. It has a fixed width and stays in the center of it's container.

Link 2: How the ScrollArea behaves with a widget in it (I wrapped the layout in a widget). https://i.imgur.com/nMaVmdi.mp4 The ScrollArea works but the layout doesn't stay in the center anymore.

What I want is for the layout to stay in the center and the ScrollArea to work too.

Note the first video (Where the ScrollArea doesn't work) is the result of the code above.

The second video is achieved by wrapping the layout in a widget and then setting it as the widget of the ScrollArea:

```
- scrollArea->setLayout(innerVerticalLayout);

+ QWidget *innerVerticalLayoutWidgetContainer = new QWidget();
+ innerVerticalLayoutWidgetContainer->setLayout(innerVerticalLayout);
+ scrollArea->setWidget(innerVerticalLayoutWidgetContainer);
```

Comment: What others have suggested you is correct. No matter what you may believe, directly setting a layout on QScrollArea is not only pointless for your problem, but also *completely wrong*. **All** QAbstractScrollArea subclasses rely on the fact that the *content* of what they would eventually scroll is set on their *viewport*; imagine the scroll area as the screen of a smartphone, and the contents as what its camera eventually captures: if you want to show something in the center of the picture, you don't move that something, you move the smartphone (aka: scroll the viewport).

Comment: Now, it's unclear what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to show some content as *centered* within the possible *scrollable area* shown in the QScrollArea? For instance, a scroll area containing three widgets laid out horizontally, and you want the middle one shown at the center of the scroll area? Then, that's a different story, not so easy to achieve, but still possible, as long as layout management is properly done and the layout manager is set on the area's `widget()`. But certainly **not** by setting a layout on the scroll area itself, because that would make scrolling impossible.

Comment: I edited the original question to show videos of how it bahaves and what I want to achieve.

"Do you want to show some content as centered within the possible scrollable area shown in the QScrollArea? For instance, a scroll area containing three widgets laid out horizontally, and you want the middle one shown at the center of the scroll area?"

Yes, but only one layout that will stay in the center.

Comment: Most of what you need requires to use [`setWidgetResizable(true)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop). If you still want the scroll area contents to have a specific minimum width, then you just need a further container (which is the one that will then be set with `setWidget()`) that will have a box layout (doesn't matter if horizontal or vertical), then add a QWidget using `Qt::AlignHCenter` and set the top vertical layout on that widget, with all the inner horizontal layouts and the other widgets.

Comment: OMG!!! It works. Thank you so much. This is a far better solution than my hacky one. How do I select this as the solution?

Comment: That depends. If only setting `setWidgetResizable(true)` worked for you, then we already have existing answers for which yours can be set as a duplicate. Otherwise I can provide a more comprehensive answer (but I won't be able to write proper C++ code, as I normally use Python).

Comment: Yes. Only setting setWidgetResizable(true) was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it.
I subscribed to the resize event of the MainWindow and made the outermost layout's (Wrapped in a widget) width match the width of the MainWindow whenever the width of the main window became larger than the width of the centered layout like so:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    if (this->width() > verticalLayoutWidgetContainer->width())
        innerVerticalLayoutWidgetContainer->setFixedWidth(this->width() - 2);
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

I added the -2 because the ScrollArea's horizontal bar would never disappear when the -2 wasn't there.